# How to create a custom route in Sails JS

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm trying to create a custom route in Sails and according to their documentation, if I add the following in `config/routes.js`:

```
'post /api/signin': 'AuthController.index',
```

The request would be dealt with by the `index` action in the `AuthController` but that doesn't seems to work at all. When I try the `/api/login` in Postman, I get nothing back.

Please note that I've added `restPrefix: '/api'` in my `config/blueprints.js`. Please note I'm using Sails 0.12.x

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are pointing to a controller with method index on it, you need to add it to your controllers and send a JSON response from there, (since you are using post). here is a simple example

### config/routes.js

```
'post /api/signin': 'AuthController.index',
```

### api/controllers/AuthController.js

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        var id = req.param('id');
        if(!id) {
          return res.json(400, { error: 'invalid company name or token'});
        }
        /* validate login..*/
        res.json(200, {data: "success"};
    }
}
```

## Update

Since you already have the above its probably caused by the blueprints you have.

### Blueprint shortcut routes

> Shortcut routes are activated by default in new Sails apps, and can be
>   turned off by setting `sails.config.blueprints.shortcuts` to `false`
>   typically in /config/blueprints.js.
>
> Sails creates shortcut routes for any controller/model pair with the
>   same identity. Note that the same action is executed for similar
>   RESTful/shortcut routes. For example, the `POST /user` and `GET
>   /user/create` routes that Sails creates when it loads
>   `api/controllers/UserController.js` and `api/models/User.js` will
>   respond by running the same code (even if you override the blueprint
>   action)

with that being said from sails blueprint documentation, maybe turning **off** shortcuts and **remove** the prefix you've added.

1. possibly the shortcuts are looking elsewhere other than your controllers thus returning 404.
2. the prefix is being added to your blueprint connected route, hence you need `/api/api/signin` to access it?

## Note

I am unable to replicate your issue on my computer as its working fine over here. but i have all blueprint settings turned off.

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
  actions: false,
  rest: false,
  shortcuts: false,
  // prefix: '',
  pluralize: false,
  populate: false,
  autoWatch: false,
};
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I have but that does't work at all. I've added `console.log(req.param())` in the index action but its like the controller is not being called at all. Al I get is a 404

Comment: I've tried disabling the prefix and also `/api/api/signin` but that didn't work either... very weird

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK try creating a new sails project and test the routing there without blueprints of models. it should work, then see the differences. probably something we both are not aware of as its working here with the code i provided. tell me what happens

Comment: That's the weirdest thing... I've done that and still doesn't work... I'm wondering if its a version issue. Will try with another version

Comment: I have created a brand new project, left it as it is (i.e.: no change in config), created a `user` model and controller, added the route and all I get is a 404. What is wrong?