# Gitlab webhook system

Tags: node.js, gitlab, sails.js

I have one question:

My application uses port 1337 (I used in sails.js framework) and I must write a webhook system from gitlab. I didn't find many tutorials on "how to write webhook system", but I have the following code:

```
const secret = "your_secret_here";
const repo = "~/your_repo_path_here/";

const http = require('http');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        let sig = "sha1=" + crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(chunk.toString()).digest('hex');

    if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] == sig) {
        exec('cd ' + repo + ' && git pull');
    }
});

    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

This code use port 8080, 
And my question: how to use this code but not on port 8080 but on my application port 1337?, How to edit this code to be the correct version for sails?

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new service using Node's `http` library. It won't work on port 1337, as that port is taken by sails.

You need to make a custom route in sails, more info on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036419/how-to-create-a-custom-route-in-sails-js), [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-routes) and [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes). And that needs to be connected to an [action](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers) which will contain the actual code which handles the webhook.

Comment: thanks, have you any tutorial to webhooks in sails?

Comment: Webhooks are just regular rest API endpoints, only difference is you kind of requested for it a while back and the external system respond to that. So semantically different, but not technically. Websockets are the ones more complex.

Comment: Added link in the answer on how to create custom rest API endpoints

Comment: do you use gitlab webhooks? i need a help to write this sytem which can get data like this https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html , and i don't have any idea how to do this